# Sort by most recent date and cluster (group) similar titles

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda, group-by

Looking for LINQ needed to sort on a date field but also have similar titles grouped and sorted.  Consider something like the following desired ordering:

```
Title                Date
"Some Title 1/3"     2009/1/3     "note1: even this is old title 3/3 causes this group to be 1st"
"Some Title 2/3"     2011/1/31    "note2: dates may not be in sequence with titles"
"Some Title 3/3"     2011/1/1     "note3: this date is most recent between "groups" of titles
"Title XYZ 1of2"     2010/2/1
"Title XYz 2of2"     2010/2/21
```

I've shown titles varying by some suffix.  What if a poster used something like the following for titles?

```
"1 LINQ Tutorial"
"2 LINQ Tutorial"
"3 LINQ Tutorial"
```

How would the query recognize these are similar titles?
You don't have to solve everything, a solution for the 1st example is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Addendum #1 20110605
@svick also Title authors typically are not thoughtful to use say 2 digits when their numbering scheme goes beyond 9. for example 01,02...10,11 etc..

Typical patterns I've seen tend to be either prefix or suffix or even buried in such as

```
1/10 1-10 ...
(1/10) (2/10) ...
1 of 10   2 of 10
Part 1  Part 2 ...
```

You pointed out a valid pattern as well:

```
xxxx Tutorial : first session,  xxxx Tutorial : second session, ....
```

If I have a Levenshtein function StringDistance( s1, s2 ) how would I fit into the LINQ query :)

Comment: Do you know that in a group, the only difference can be in a number? In other words, should `LINQ Tutorial: Starting` and `LINQ Tutorial: Finishing` be in the same group?

Comment: They probably should be.  The first pattern is more typical though I've seen people use different styles in their titles, something I can't control :)   I can't believe I opened a can of worms, this brings some memories from college time :)   Say I was able to derive some levingshtein function in C# how would it be applied to the query posted?  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, let's say you have that and you define some rule for when are strings considered similar. What should happen if title `A` is considered similar to `B` and `B` to `C`, but `A` isn't considered similar to `C`?

Comment: I have not slept the night so after I review the listed references I may have a better answer than that I am not looking for "a handle all situations" solution but if I cover 90% of the typical patterns I will be happy.  Most of the time I am trying to achieve "simple things in my mind" like here sorting a bunch of videos I am not sure my currently aching brain can handle theory/algorithm right at the moment. My common roads blocks are LINQ/Lambda syntax and constantly changing MS landscape.  My brain is about to melt, I am going to bed :)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't laugh my model in some DLL
  ' 20110505
    Public Sub Sort()
       
        xdoc.Root.ReplaceAll(xdoc.Descendants("MEDIA").OrderByDescending(Function(e) DateOrNull(e.Element("PDT").Value)))
    End Sub


my View (unbound yet) 


listBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PDate", ListSortDirection.Descending));

Ha ha! you have a good day.

Comment: @svick  see Addendum #1 in main post, I struggle here in comments with formatting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal grouping in LINQ (and in SQL, but that's not relevant here) works by selecting some key for every element in the collection. You don't have such key, so I wouldn't use LINQ, but two nested `foreach`es:

```
var groups = new List<List<Book>>();

foreach (var book in books)
{
    bool found = false;

    foreach (var g in groups)
    {
        if (sameGroup(book.Title, g[0].Title))
        {
            found = true;
            g.Add(book);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
        groups.Add(new List<Book> { book });
}

var result = groups.Select(g => g.OrderBy(b => b.Date).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

This gradually creates a list of groups. Each book is compared with the first one in each group. If it matches, it is added to the group. If no group matched, the book creates a new group. In the end, we sort the results using LINQ with dot notation.

It would be more correct if books were compared with each book in a group, not just the first. But you're may not get completely correct results anyway, so I think this optimization is worth it.

This has time complexity `O(N²)`, so it's probably not the best solution if you had millions of books.

**EDIT:** To sort the groups, use something like

```
groups.OrderBy(g => g.Max(b => b.Date))
```

Comment: Thanks for this step towards a solution I've combined your code with Muhammad's LINQPad.  I understand the nested foreach and grouping seems to be working but I don't know 1) how to cause sorting of titles within the groups. Can it be done in the LINQ?  if I OrderBy Title the groups are not sorted by one of their most recent dates <br> 2) how to get sorting to work for titles where "10-12 CTitle" is currently falling before "2-12 CTitle" ?

Comment: The last line of my solution does sorting by date.

Comment: Your last line sorts by dates within a collection of similar titles however what I was after is somehow adding say a temporary sorting column "SortDate" whose value would the most recent date for each group (of similar titles) the groups are then sorted using this date.

Comment: Regarding sorting title within groups I found the following [post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx)  regarding "Natural order"   Is there anything builtin w/in LINQ .NET regarding this kind of sorting?

Comment: @svick thanks I am using the following per your help
` var r1 = groups.Select(g => g.OrderBy(b => b.Title)); `
 
` var result = r1.OrderByDescending(g => g.Max(b => b.Date))`

 and it's getting the groups sorted by their respective max date and the titles sorted.  I think you've help me enough I will mark your as answer.  I will work on understand how to incorporate the IComparer for "human string sorting" discussed [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SortingStringsForHumans.aspx) Thanks for helping me surf the LINQ/C# galaxy :)

Answer (score 0):

For ordering by date you should use the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) operator.

Example:

```
//Assuming your table is called Table in datacontext ctx
var data = from t in ctx.Table
           order by t.Date
           select t;
```

For grouping strings after similarity you should consider something like the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or the [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) algorithm. (Although I do not know any direct implementations of these in .Net).

**EDIT**: As suggested in the comment by svick, the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_Distance) may also be considered, as a better alternative to the Hamming distance.

Comment: I think Levenshtein distance would be better in this case. Hamming distance would say that `2 Tutorial ` and `10 Tutorial` are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Title and Date fields are contained in class called model consider the following class definition
public class Model

```
{
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public string Prefix
    {get
        {
            return Title.Substring(0,Title.LastIndexOf(' '));
        }
    }
}
```

Alongside Date and Title properties i have created a prefix property with no setter and it is returning us the common prefix using substring. you can use any method of your choice in getter of this property. Rest of job is simple. Consider this Linqpad program

```
void Main()
{
    var model = new List<Model>{new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,3), Title = "Some Title 1/3"},
                new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,1), Title = "Some Title 2/3"},
                    new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,1), Title = "Some Title 3/3"},
                    new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,31), Title = "Title XYZ 1of2"},
                    new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,31), Title = "Title XYZ 2of2"}};
            var result = model.OrderBy(x => x.Date).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Edits >>>
If we put the prefix aside the query itself is not returning what I was after which is: 1) Sort the groups by their most recent date 2) sort by title within clusters.  Try the following

```
var model = new List<Model>{

                new Model{Date = new DateTime(2009,1,3), Title = "BTitle 1/3"},
                new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,31), Title = "BTitle 2/3"},
                new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,1), Title = "BTitle 3/3"},

                new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,31), Title = "ATitle XYZ 2of2"},
                new Model{Date = new DateTime(2011,1,31), Title = "ATitle XYZ 1of2"}
                };
        var result = model.OrderBy(x => x.Date).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out LinqPad something I will need to download and try out.  Thanks for also for showing working code/sample.  See addendum #1 to main post would you handle the cases I am seeing by coding a more complex Prefix? Should I be considering using RegExp to strip off typical varying title parts?

Comment: BTitle 3/3 is coming before BTitle 2/3.

Comment: use sorting like var result = model.OrderBy(x => new{x.Date,x.Title}).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix);

Comment: I am not sure I understand new(x.Date, x.Title) portion of your modified query??  LinkPad is saying "At least one object must implement IComparable."